# What function is to small for spawning into an own process

Tags: erlang

Where is the limit where there is no benefit of spawning a process to make a more parallelized function call?

For example when doing a recursive lookup in a tree structure, each child node would add a process and a message call to the parent just for a simple comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spawning process and do the work will be always slower than just do the work. It strongly depend on your exact requirements. Especially non-function requirements are the key. So go and do measurements. It's pretty easy. See documentation about [Profiling](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/profiling.html) for more details and there are also 3rd party projects easing benchmarking over there.

Answer (score 0):

Spawning more processes won't necessarily make tasks run in parallel.  For example, if you have a 24 cores on your system, only 24 processes can run at any one time.

Instead it might be good to think about how much work is being done when you examine a node in a tree.  Lets say the node value represents a url which needs to be called to retrieve a value. In this case it might be a good idea to spawn a process for each node.  This way a process can be scheduled to run while another process is waiting for an answer to the http request.

Comment: Maybe I thought of this wrong when I asked the question but in my example with a lookup in a tree I would be able to make 24 lookups simultaneously (if I had 24 cores). If the lookup on each node is only to compare a value would _could it_ be cheaper to make all lookups sequential (just map over the tree) instead of spawning processes for each node and compare them 24 at a time.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't care about this at all since it just implementation details and wouldn't do much in total speed and would certainly make it less readable?